# Error message while installing App - INSTALL FAILED NO MATCHING ABIS

Tags: android, adb

I tried to install the app through `ADB` using terminal, but it fails with the error message like this :

> "INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

***INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS***

When you are trying to install an app that has native libraries and it doesn't have a native library for the cpu architecture that you are installing at.

For example if you have compiled an app for *armv7* only and you are trying to install it on an emulator or device that uses the *Intel or different architecture* it will not install and will throw this error.

*The app has no support for the architecture you are installing.*