# Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS

Tags: android, android-emulator, arm, x86-64

I'm getting this error **selectively** (not everytime) on the same device (x86_64 lollipop emulator):

> Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS.
>   It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.
>
> WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!
>
> Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

Next, when I press OK, it shows me this:

> pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.packagename.apps.rp
>   Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS]
>
> $ adb shell pm uninstall com.packagename.apps.rp
>   DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR
>   Error while Installing APK

Multiple such questions have been asked and answered, and I've followed most of them:

1. I used ARM architecture emulator to run the code as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572052/install-failed-no-matching-abis-when-install-apk) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30914560/error-message-while-installing-app-install-failed-no-matching-abis), it worked, but it's too slow
2. I tried the change in gradle as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33178914/5038993), but that was of no help.

Now, a couple of days later, I tried it again on the same x86 emulator and the app is running all good.

I've had similar problem a couple of times in the past. Android Studio will show me this error - no solutions working, and a few days later when I retry it, it would run fine.

Why is it happening? What could be the root cause for such unexpected behavior?

Comment: Try this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49473570/3400991 for **Android 3.0.1**